# Can someone explain to me why I can not use "to be" after "quieter"

Tags: grammar

Can someone explain to me why I can not use "to be" after "quieter".

> Life's so much quieter **to be** away from the city.

> Life's so much quieter away from the city.

Comment: @Sam : are you sure about that?

Comment: Because you need an extraposed "dummy" **it** to stand in place of the clause headed by the infinitive "to be". *To be away from the city is so much quieter* => "It is so much quieter to be away from the city".

Comment: Life is so much quieter away from the city. Life away from the city is so much quieter.

Comment: Also, we say "Could someone please explain" or "Would someone please explain" not "May someone please explain".  Someone may explain it, but "May" at the beginning of a sentence is seeking *permission*, or expressing a wish or hope, as in *May you prosper!* or *May there be peace on earth!*

Comment: I don't see why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: In addition to the grammatical points already brought up, the issue is partially a semantic one: your actions aren't quiet, your environment is, so _life_ is the most appropriate word to modify.

Comment: @Lambie It's correct, but it's a little disjointed and hard to extract the relevant commentary from. I didn't downvote, but I can't upvote.

Comment: You need either <nothing> OR a "finite, **stative**" verb in place of ***to be*** - *Life's so much quieter [**being**] away from the city*. More naturally, *Life's so much quieter **living** away from the city.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Being or living, same idea or nothing.  Anyway, I changed my answer.

Comment: Please explain why you think this should be correct.  For example you could give an example of correct English that you think has the same structure.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence, "away from the city" is an adverbial phrase that answers the question, "Where". Where is life so much quieter? Away from the city. It can also be rearranged with the adverbial at the beginning of the sentence:

> Away from the city, life is so much quieter.

You may be thinking of a structure like this:

> **It's** so much quieter to be away from the city.

There, the pronoun "it" refers forward to the infinitive "to be away from the city". With that phrase in subject place, it looks like this:

> To be away from the city is much quieter.

But with "life" as the subject, you can't have "to" anymore:

> *[To be away from the city] [life] is so much quieter.

There's two different subjects [in brackets], so the grammar is bad.

Answer (score 0):

Life's so much quieter to be away from the city. [not grammatical]

To be away from the city makes life so much quieter. [grammatical]
Being away from the city makes life so much quieter. [grammatical]

Life's so much quieter **away from the city**. [**adverbial phrase. prepositional phrase**, **grammatical**]

Generally, to + action verb would come after like, love, hate, etc., not a stative verb like "be".

"He loves to play tennis".
"I'd like or love to be rich". like + to infinitive.

to be rich [to be + adjective] to be plus an adjective is the usual form.